# CSS grid systems offsets columns etc

Tags: css

I know probably most of you know all of these stuff but still maybe out there are people like me who are just starting to learn these stuff about grids in css. and maybe these questions will help them too.

1. What are grid systems ?
2. how to calculate a grid system in pixels and percentages ?
3. What are offsets? How to calculate offsets ?
4. Is it better to use a grid system ?

Comment: Why you don't just google your questions? This question isn't related to a specific problem or issue.

Comment: i googled a little bit didn't found anything concrete about how to calculate the grid specially the offsets, since you told me to google maybe you know a website where i can find the answer to these questions or a part of them. If you are kind can you share the link ? i've spend a weekend searching and reading about grids.. :-)

Comment: I've gone through dozens of good articles, tutorials and so on about this and related topics, but I don't know which of them suite your needs. I don't know where you stand with your knowledge about this topic. I believe you'll have the best results by searching for yourself. Learn step-by-step and don't start in the middle. It's also good to refresh some of your knowledge on the way to grid systems, responsive web design what so ever.

Answer (score 2):

As you have probably already encountered there are so many different grids and css frameworks it can be a little confusing, so I will try my best to help.

Grids are nothing more than an area of screen broken down into segments. Most grids are typically split into groups of 12 (or multiples of twelve). So with a container 960px wide and having 12 groups (which I will now call columns) each column is 80px wide.

Calculating grids can be complex and when combined with adding gutters, offsets, margins, nesting, containers, etc. your css can get rather messy pretty quickly.

There are a number of grid based css frameworks out there with the two most popular being [Bootstrap by Twitter](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) and the [Foundation by Zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com/). I believe that these two have grown in popularity over Blueprint CSS and 960 grid + others as they offer a wide range of plugins as well as layers of scaffolding to help building really nice looking responsive websites.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very true.. i found a lot of different grids on different dimensions and different column counts most common one is 12.
Noticed is a little bit complicated to calculate that's why i came here to ask someone around here.
Been playing with twitter so far :-) foundation didn't try it